# Changing Wamp Server directory

Tags: wamp

I have managed to change the wamp directory to what I want. However, now I get a error on the wamp index page. On wamp index I get "unable to open WampServer config files"

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click on **WampServer** icon in taskbar. Select Apache > httpd.conf from the pullup. Search for the term “`DocumentRoot`” **Change** the DocumentRoot path to your custom **directory** [[1]](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/43522/how-to-change-the-www-root-directory-on-wampserver)

Comment: I did do that. However, when I open the wamp index.php file, it gives me that error.

Comment: I think you need to change some variables in `index.php` to conform the new directory, see these topics [1](http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,116674,116675)  [2](http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,128033,128069)

Comment: A better solution would be to use Apache's Virtual Hosts